# Fixing header using position fixed causes content to jump underneath header during scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap's Affix plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) to fix my header to top after scrolling down 80px. Now this makes the headers position fixed.
As soon as the header gets the position fixed, the page content slides/jumps about 44px which is the same as the height of the fixed header.

To fix this, I've tried using JavaScript that adds a `margin-top` equal the height of the header to the content container after scrolling 80px.

Here is my JS code for that

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(height >= 80) {
        $('.content-container').css('margin-top', '44px');
    } else {
        $('.content-container').css('margin-top', '0px');
    }
});
```

Now this works as expected but as long as the page is being loaded, the header doesn't get fixed to the top after scrolling and this gives a glitchy experience. Is there a solution to this problem using CSS only?

You can see the header in action on my website - [www.edmhunters.com](http://www.edmhunters.com)

Comment: `position:fixed` takes an element out of normal flow, it doesn’t influence the position of what comes after it any more. So if you had your element in normal flow before, and now take it out, of course the rest of the content “jumps”. The easiest way around this – if your header’s height is known – would probably be to have it be `position:absolute` to begin with, because that also takes it out of the flow, so that you can take that into account from the start and keep the following content at bay via a margin or padding.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. That did the trick. Add it as an answer and i'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:fixed` takes an element out of normal flow, it doesn’t influence the position of what comes after it any more. So if you had your element in normal flow before, and now take it out, of course the rest of the content “jumps”.

The easiest way around this – if your header’s height is known – would probably be to have it be `position:absolute` to begin with, because that also takes it out of the flow, so that you can take that into account from the start and keep the following content at bay via a margin or padding.